# How to fix an order column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Ok, so this is not the typical question on how to run a query with ASC or DESC. What I need to do is the following:
I have the following table:
[MySQL Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Gtq.png).

I need to run a query that fixes the orders. In other words, that the values for `order` are modified to (1-10) correctly. The result of running such query would be the following table:
[MySQL correct orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3nXp.png)

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, @rank := @rank + 1 as new_order
from your_table
cross join (select @rank := 0) r
order by `order`
```